# Inserting html tags into string in parentheses with c#

Tags: c#, regex

Although I googled many searching, I didn't find a satisfactory result. I'm new to Regex, so I couldn't write anything. I have string like this: `[Whatever You Want (WYW)]`. And I want to get a result like this: `[Whatever You Want (<b>WYW</b>)]`. But strings change every condition like `[New String (NS)]` or `[Other string (OTS)]` etc.

I am aware that similar questions are asked here. But I couldn't reach a solution, I had to write it here.

I think, I have to use Regex but I have no idea. How can I do it?

Comment: Please check the linked question, try something, and if you fail please come back to share your findings and precise the problem.

Comment: In its very simplest, sub-optimal form, `var newString = oldString.Replace(findThis, $"<b>{findThis}</b>");` The fact that it's HTML probably isn't relevant. You're just finding a string and replacing it with a new string (which happens to contain the original string.) Regex *might* be good solution, but for now what you're doing looks like a really simple find-and-replace. For performance, perhaps use [`StringBuiilder.Replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524528/string-replace-vs-stringbuilder-replace).

Comment: @WiktorStribizew, I did not see any expression that written in c#.

Comment: @ScottHannen, Thank for your comment. I edited my question. The strings change for every condition. The only common expression is parentheses ().

Comment: So what you want is to find every instance of a pair of parentheses and wrap the contents of the parentheses - regardless of what they are - in bold tags. Do the square brackets figure in at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"\(([^()]*)\)", "(<b>$1</b>)")
```

[**.NET regex demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%29%5c%29&i=%5bWhatever+You+Want+%28WYW%29%5d&r=%28%3cb%3e%241%3c%2fb%3e%29)

[**C# demo**](http://ideone.com/nEuFgX):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "[Whatever You Want (WYW)]";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"\(([^()]*)\)", "(<b>$1</b>)"));
    }
}
```

Output: `[Whatever You Want (<b>WYW</b>)]`