# string.Replace or stringBuilder.Replace()

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I'm new to C#, so please forgive me my mistakes.

I want to replace some part of a string, every time that piece of code is called (2-4 times per call). 
I was wondering which method is better to use in terms of performance: `string.Replace` or `stringBuilder.Replace()`?

What if this piece of code is called 10.000 times concurrently??

Comment: If you have a `StringBuilder` use `StringBuilder.Replace`, if you have a `String` use `String.Replace`. So basically you are asking what is faster, a `String` or a `StringBuilder`. That depends, measure it yourself. Write clear and readable code first and  optimize for performance later if you really need.

Comment: Be aware, this two `Replace` method uses by different classes. So..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is StringBuilder.Replace() more efficient than String.Replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287842/is-stringbuilder-replace-more-efficient-than-string-replace)

Answer (score 6):

The best way to find out which one is faster is to benchmark it for your particular problem - write a simple test harness and time the two options.

Having said that - C# strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), which means you can't change them after they are created. When you call `String.Replace` the runtime has to create a new `String` instance for the result. This means that a sequence of changes to the same string will be slow, because the runtime has to create a new object for each manipulation, allocating memory and copying the string data each time.

`StringBuilder` was specifically designed as a mutable string for this type of situation - to avoid creating a new `String` instance on each manipulation.

So `StringBuilder` will almost certainly be faster if you're doing a sequence of `Replace` calls on the same string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Replace()` after your string is made,it will replace at all the places at once.
it would be Better if you explain your scenario with some example.

Look at this link it has a good description: [Comparing RegEx.Replace, String.Replace and StringBuilder.Replace – Which has better performance?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx)

Comment: Updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/debuggingtoolbox/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance

Answer (score 0):

`String` Replace is different from `StringBuilder` Replace. But on the surface they are the same.
StringBuilder is purely an optimization, but considering the prevalence of string usage, it is critical.`String.Replace` always creates a new string – `StringBuilder.Replace` doesn't.