# Why there is no StringBuilder.replace() in Java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

From the post [String Builder Replace() is faster then string replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287842/is-stringbuilder-replace-more-efficient-than-string-replace) in .NET language

I want to know if same answer is valid for java as well or not.

I checked and found

```
StringBuilder builder = ...;
builder = new StringBuilder(builder.toString().replace("from", "to"));
```

is inefficient as `StringBuilder.toString()` is an expensive operation.

Why JAVA does not have `replace` method in string builder class ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: There is a `replace(int, int, String)` method and also an `indexOf(String, int)` method. I guess you can use these to write your own `replace(String, String)` method.

Comment: Docs does not mentioned this thing that is why i came here !

Comment: +jsheeran It's not what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Who knows? Why doesn't C# have something that Java has? Like...applets!

Comment: @Kayaman-- Don't compare apple and oranges I am talking about similar functionality here that both language's posses.

Comment: Well, because they're not the same language. I was being facetious about applets, but while Java and C# resemble each other, they're not the same language and therefore there are even significant differences in how some things are handled. I don't think either of the language's philosophy is to have all the functionality of the other one. Also, it's not JAVA, it's Java.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) :

> **StringBuilder** objects are like String objects, except that they can be
>   modified. Internally, **these objects are treated like variable-length
>   arrays that contain a sequence of characters**. At any point, the length
>   and content of the sequence can be changed through method invocations

for that the [`StringBuilder::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) is like :

```
public StringBuilder replace(int start, int end, String str)
```

Instead of [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), because it is *treated like an array and not a String*